# E-mail Template not displaying correctly on different platforms

Tags: html, css, email

This is probably a very simply and stupid problem but I can't seem to figure it out. I've made a template for someone using Foundation's E-mail stuff. It looks fine in Chrome, Device mode: 
https://i.gyazo.com/3ed8b1fab357d9380b4c165bd6fd0475.png

It also looks fine in MailChimp.

But now, when I test it in Litmus and send it to my own e-mail, things get pretty weird:

- Litmus > Looks fine on iPhone, but the rest is really messed up.
- Gmail > The bottom text is somehow aligned next to the container box (on the flower background), the text styles are NOT working, and on mobile view it's EVEN WORSE.

Here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/1s6T9ewB

Sorry for the pastebin link, I can't post more than so many characters it says

Comment: I didn't look too deeply into your code, but right off the bat I can tell you that having your styles in a `<style>` tag is a big email no-no. Either use Foundation's inlining tools or something like this http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/, that will definitely help.

Comment: Alright trying that now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yup that worked. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I can accept it and have this closed.

Comment: Great! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your styles in a  tag is a big email no-no.
Do either of these

- Foundation's inlining tools. Or
- Something like [this](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css).

Comment: Hi, it seemed to work for a while but as I kept working on the template the styles do not go inline anymore after using the inliner. What can cause this? I have used some inline styles myself on a couple of items, should I not have done that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure... but you may need to keep your working copy with the styles in the `<style>` tag and then just inline when you're all finished. Either that, or if you're comfortable using the command-line/a little JS, there is a Gulp task that will do this for you as you work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-css

Comment: When I first used the inliner on Foundation itself it was working fine. Then I edit a couple things because I didn't like them. Now when I upload my HTML and CSS to Foundation it says that "there is an error in my code". However I do not seem to find one. And the Mailchimp inliner Does inline my styles HOWEVER they do not work :( What the heck is going on here??